# how do i authenticate against cybersource soap toolkit api on php

Tags: php, soap, cybersource

I have the following code on my index.php

```
<?php
// This sample demonstrates how to run a sale request, which combines an
// authorization with a capture in one request.

// Using Composer-generated autoload file.
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Or, uncomment the line below if you're not using Composer autoloader.
//require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/CybsSoapClient.php');


// Before using this example, you can use your own reference code for the transaction.
$referenceCode = 'holla';

$client = new CybsSoapClient();
$request = $client->createRequest($referenceCode);

// Build a sale request (combining an auth and capture). In this example only
// the amount is provided for the purchase total.
$ccAuthService = new stdClass();
$ccAuthService->run = 'true';
$request->ccAuthService = $ccAuthService;

$ccCaptureService = new stdClass();
$ccCaptureService->run = 'true';
$request->ccCaptureService = $ccCaptureService;

$billTo = new stdClass();
$billTo->firstName = 'John';
$billTo->lastName = 'Doe';
$billTo->street1 = '1295 Charleston Road';
$billTo->city = 'Mountain View';
$billTo->state = 'CA';
$billTo->postalCode = '94043';
$billTo->country = 'US';
$billTo->email = 'null@cybersource.com';
$billTo->ipAddress = '10.7.111.111';
$request->billTo = $billTo;

$card = new stdClass();
$card->accountNumber = '4111111111111111';
$card->expirationMonth = '12';
$card->expirationYear = '2020';
$request->card = $card;

$purchaseTotals = new stdClass();
$purchaseTotals->currency = 'USD';
$purchaseTotals->grandTotalAmount = '90.01';
$request->purchaseTotals = $purchaseTotals;

$reply = $client->runTransaction($request);

// This section will show all the reply fields.
print("\nRESPONSE: " . print_r($reply, true));
```

and the cybs.ini is like

```
merchant_id = "firefy"
transaction_key = "5430494897960177107046"

; Modify the URL to point to either a live or test WSDL file with the desired API version.
wsdl = "https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.109.wsdl"
```

when i run the code on my local machine i get the following error messaage.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [wsse:FailedCheck] Security Data : UsernameToken authentication failed. in C:\xampp\htdocs\cybersourceTest\index.php:50 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cybersourceTest\index.php(50): SoapClient->__call('runTransaction', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cybersourceTest\index.php on line 50
```

How do i know what caused the error above and how can i solve the above error.
I am trying to add payout api to my app and this is giving a headache right now.
Please guys help me out if anyone can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error “authentication failed” is saying your merchant_id and transaction_key are not correct.

Assuming that your merchant_id is correct your transaction_key is not the correct format. You can get a transaction_key by going to the business center at https://ebctest.cybersource.com then go to Account Management-> Transaction Security Keys -> Security Keys for the SOAP Toolkit API. Generate a key there.

Comment: I did find the transaction key for but i still cant get the error to go away. i got a key that is like 100 characters long. i tried that but still the same error comes up.

Comment: I tried that but nothing is happening the same error keeps popping up. i added the transaction key that i was given. it is like 100characters long and the merchant id .what am i missing merchant_id=firefy and transaction_key="the_transaction_key_i_was_given_by_Cybersource_here"

Comment: i will mark your answer correct anyway because you gave me insight to what i was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I found out that i the url that i was pointing to was not valid or something but i fixed it by changing the endpoint of the wsdl from**

```
wsdl="https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.109.wsdl"
```

to

```
wsdl="https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.151.wsdl"
```

**That took care of everything that was wrong with the error that was popping up.**

Comment: Apologies for digging up an old thread but...
How did you know to update this?

Comment: the explanation is on the reference manual on the type of wsdl you need to use.